# Spark dataframe execution stuck for Sort & dropDuplicates operations

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with 1.4 billion rows and 20 columns. here is my code

```
df = sqlContext.read.parquet('path0')
df = df.sort('col_10')
df = df.dropDuplicates(['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3', 'col_4', 'col_5'])
df.write.parquet('path1')
```

for the last write operation out of total 200 tasks, it completes 194 tasks in less time(~6min) but to complete remaining 6 tasks it is taking ~30min.

what's causing spark unable to parallelize the tasks properly?